# After changing lcd get parent directory of original file

Tags: working-directory

Is is possible to get the original working directory of vim after changing the local working directory?

Let's say I open vim with parent directory:

`~/projects/myproject`

and then I open a file and change the working directory:

`~/projects/myproject/tasks/mytask.js`

```
autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h
```

**GOAL:** I want to get the directory name:

`~/projects/myproject`

NOT:

`~/projects/myproject/tasks`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

#### Fugitive

If your project is under git's control then you use [Fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive).

```
:echo fugitive#repo().tree()
```

To edit a file relative to the git root you an use `:Gedit` and a `/`:

```
:Gedit /tasks/mytask.js
```

For more help see:

```
:h fugitive
:h :Gedit
```

#### Projectionist

If you are using [Projectionist.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) then you can get the inner most directory by doing the following:

```
:echo projectionist#path()
```

Projectionist also provides `:Cd` to change the directory from the project root. `:ProjectDo {cmd}` will run command, `{cmd}`, from the project root.

For more help see:

```
:h projectionist
:h :Cd
:h :ProjectDo
:h projectionist#path()
```

#### Low-tech solution

Forget "auto-cd-ing" to the current file's directory. Just set your current path to your project's root. Use a nice fuzzyfinder like [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) to navigate your files.

You can use `%:h` to get the current file's directory:

```
:e %:h
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'autochdir'
:h c_%
:h filename-modifiers
```

#### Thoughts

Personally I use projectionist for my project needs, however I also keep the current working directory at my project root and never change it. This keeps things simple.

If you do insist on "auto-cd-ing" then I would recommend you look into `'autochdir`. See `:h 'autochdir'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
:echo system("pwd")
```

should give you the information you want.

Comment: Not sure if I have a plugin that is interfering or not. But it's just returning the same info if I did plain `pwd`. I just ended up creating a global variable store the first opened file. `let g:projectDir = get(g:, 'projectDir', expand('%:p:h'))`

Comment: When Vim runs an external command, either through `:!` or `system()`, it uses the working directory that was set via `:cd` or `:lcd`, so this won't work.